# PHP-FPM and ProxyPass disables the possibility to use FilesMatch?

Tags: php-fpm, proxypass, mod-proxy-fcgi

i'm using PHP-FPM and mod_proxy_fcgi for serving PHP files. The system is blazing fast and works flawlessly except i'm not able to use the FilesMatch directive in Apache. Well that makes sense because the proxypass is defined to take over any php file.

Are there any possibilities to get the FilesMatch somehow to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i gave up because it's impossible to do. So i stopped using ProxPass and went along with this solution:

http://www.sysadminslife.com/linux/howto-apache-mit-php-fpm-und-mod-fastcgi-unter-debian-wheezy/

Answer (score -1):

I don't suppose you came across an answer? I'm looking at doing something like this:

```
<Proxy *>
    Require all granted
</Proxy>
<Location />
    ProxyPass fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/
    ProxyPassReverse fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/
</Location>
<Location /static>
    ProxyPass !
</Location>
```

However I haven't tested that yet. That would require all static assets to be served out of the `/static` directory.